# Should I qualify pointer parameters with volatile if they may be changed during the execution of a function?

Tags: c++, c, volatile

Say I have the function

```
int foo(int * const bar){
    while(!*bar){
        printf("qwertyuiop\n");
    }
}
```

where I intend to change the value at `bar` to something other than 0 to stop this loop. Would it be appropriate to instead write it as below?

```
int foo(int volatile * const bar){
    while(!*bar){
        printf("qwertyuiop\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: "_where I intend to change the value_": What exactly does that mean? How is the value changed?

Comment: `volatile` is not for multithreading. If a different thread changes the value, you need an `atomic`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`volatile` was intended for things like memory-mapped device registers, where the pointed-to value could "magically" change "behind the compiler's back" due to the nature of the hardware involved.  Assuming you're not writing code that deals with special hardware that might "spontaneously" change the value that `bar` points to, then you needn't (and shouldn't) use the `volatile` keyword.  Simply omitting the `const` keyword is sufficient to let the compiler (and any programmer that might call the function) know that the pointed-to value is subject to change.

Note that if you are intending to set `*bar` *from another thread*, then the `volatile` keyword isn't *good enough*; even if you tag the pointer volatile, the compiler still won't guarantee correct handling.  For that use-case to work correctly, you need to either synchronize all reads and writes to `*bar` with a mutex, or alternatively use a `std::atomic<int>` instead of a plain `int`.

Comment: Agreed; however `const T * bar` will function as a promise that `foo()` won't change the `int` value pointed to by `bar`.  (it's only a promise and not a guarantee because a sufficiently tricksy programmer could still change `bar` within `foo()` by using `const_cast`, but we'll assume fair play here :) )

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux This was my intent. The pointer that `foo()` has does not change but the value at that location does.